# How to use profiles or targets to get the values from xml properties file using a template file

Tags: xml, maven, xslt, ant, maven-plugin

Using Maven or Ant wanted to get the values from an xml file and replace it by its variables using targets/profiles.

properties.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<variables>
    <variable id="Title">
      <book.01>abc</book.01>
      <book.02>def</book.01>
      <ebook.03>ghi</book.01>
      <ebook.04>klmn</book.01>
    </variable>
    <variable id="Author">
      <book.01>john</book.01>
      <book.02>jack</book.01>
      <ebook.03>simi</book.01>
      <ebook.04>laura</book.01>
    </variable>
</variables>
```

Using Maven or Ant if I select "book.01" as target or profile, I want to replace the values in Template.xml with values of "book.01" from properties.xml

Current Template.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
        name="abc.jndi:name=JNDIProp">
        <attribute name="myprop" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">               
                <jndi:binding
                    name="Title">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @book.01@
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="Author">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @book.01@
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings> 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
<projects>
```

Expected output is:book.01.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
        name="abc.jndi:name=JNDIProp">
        <attribute name="myprop" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">               
                <jndi:binding
                    name="Title">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        abc
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="Author">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        john
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings> 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
<projects>
```

But wanted to know how should i use same template when i want to run the values for "book.02" or "ebook.03" profiles/target.

Note: The maven profile name/ant target name will be matching the variables of template.xml `@varaible@` name.
Example: `mvn -P book.01` or `ant ebook.01`

**UPDATES:**

With the help of @Ken xsl stylesheet file, I have used the xml-maven plugin to transform the template.xml.Using maven-replacer-plugin I was able to change the `@book.01@` varaible in template.xml and replace it with the profile name.

Example:

```
   <profile>
        <id>book.02</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>                    
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <ignoreMissingFile>true</ignoreMissingFile>
                <file>template.xml</file>
                <outputFile>
                    target/template.xml
                </outputFile>
                <regex>false</regex>
                <token>@book.01@</token>
                <value>@book.02@</value>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I have resolved the problem with maven-xml-plugin and Saxon dependency for xml transforming and Adopted the solution the @ken has provided with an additional maven replacer plugin to replace the @book.01@ varaible using maven profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking for help, or are you asking for people to solve your entire problem for you?  It is obvious that you haven't worked with the above data files because neither of them are well-formed.  You are asking volunteers to fix your XML before giving you a complete answer.  I suggest in the future that you try to solve the problem first and then ask questions.  That way you can be directed regarding *where* you are having a problem in your understanding, and the files that you post will at least be well-formed.

A solution is below, as I suspect other readers may be interested in the approach using `<xsl:analyze-string>`.

t:\ftemp>type properties.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<variables>
    <variable id="Title">
      <book.01>abc</book.01>
      <book.02>def</book.02>
      <ebook.03>ghi</ebook.03>
      <ebook.04>klmn</ebook.04>
    </variable>
    <variable id="Author">
      <book.01>john</book.01>
      <book.02>jack</book.02>
      <ebook.03>simi</ebook.03>
      <ebook.04>laura</ebook.04>
    </variable>
</variables>
```

t:\ftemp>type Template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
        name="abc.jndi:name=JNDIProp">
        <attribute name="myprop" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">               
                <jndi:binding
                    name="Title">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @book.01@
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="Author">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @book.01@
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings> 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</projects>
```

t:\ftemp>call xslt2 Template.xml properties.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><projects>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="abc.jndi:name=JNDIProp">
        <attribute name="myprop" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">               
                <jndi:binding name="Title">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        abc
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="Author">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        john
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings> 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</projects>
```

t:\ftemp>type properties.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="props" match="variable/*"
         use="concat(../@id,'&#xd;',name(.))"/>

<xsl:template match="j:value" xmlns:j="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../@name"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="@(.*?)@">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="key('props',concat($id,'&#xd;',regex-group(1)),
                      doc('properties.xml'))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

t:\ftemp>rem Done!

Comment: Hello Ken and Mark, I really appreciate your work and thanks for your precious time for writing this solution up and giving inputs for asking future questions. @Ken the reason I put this question is to get the suggestions on how to improve overall problem that i am currently having. 1.Improving the template.xml so that based on profile/targets that i choose the output of the template.xml should change. 2. Need to work on xslt to accomodate this profile/target change. Example: if choose book.01 as maven profile or ant target the output of template.xml should change based on properties.xml file.

Comment: @Ken, I have tested this code by using [maven-xml-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) transform functionality. It works fine only with `<book.01>values</book.01>`. Example: If I change my template.xml to `@book.02@` the values of `<book.02>values</book.02>` from properties.xml are not copied to ouput file, I am still seeing the values of `<book.01>values</book.01>`

Comment: In my test environment I changed "@book.01@ to be "@book.02@" and I now get "def" instead of "abc", and "jack" instead of "john" without any changes to my stylesheet.  It sounds to me like your environment does not support XSLT 2.0 properly (though if you were running an XSLT 1.0 processor I would have expected an error to be reported).  I use Saxon, the gold standard for XSLT transformation.

Comment: @Ken thanks for clarification, I had to clear up old verion of saxon and had to install saxon-he 9.4 to get this work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XSLT transformation to generate XML files. ANT has a built in [xslt task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html).

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── resources
│       ├── properties.xml
│       └── template1.xsl
└── target
    └── result.xml
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="transform">

   <property name="resources.dir" location="src/resources"/>
   <property name="build.dir"     location="target"/>

   <target name="transform">
      <xslt style="${resources.dir}/template1.xsl" in="${resources.dir}/properties.xml" out="${build.dir}/result.xml"/>
   </target>

   <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
   </target>

</project>
```

### properties.xml

Your original data was not well-formed. This is my assumption of the correct file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<variables>
    <variable id="Title">
      <book.01>abc</book.01>
      <book.02>def</book.02>
      <ebook.03>ghi</ebook.03>
      <ebook.04>klmn</ebook.04>
    </variable>
    <variable id="Author">
      <book.01>john</book.01>
      <book.02>jack</book.02>
      <ebook.03>simi</ebook.03>
      <ebook.04>laura</ebook.04>
    </variable>
</variables>
```

### template1.xsl

This is the stylesheet used as a template for the output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
                xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <projects>
         <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="abc.jndi:name=JNDIProp">
            <attribute name="myprop" serialDataType="jbxb">
               <jndi:bindings xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" >               
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="//variable[@id='Title']/book.01"  mode="title"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="//variable[@id='Author']/book.01" mode="author"/>
               </jndi:bindings> 
            </attribute>
         </mbean>
      </projects>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="book.01" mode="title">
      <jndi:binding name="Title">
         <jndi:value type="java.lang.String"><xsl:value-of select="."/></jndi:value>
      </jndi:binding>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="book.01" mode="author">
      <jndi:binding name="Author">
         <jndi:value type="java.lang.String"><xsl:value-of select="."/></jndi:value>
      </jndi:binding>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- This example uses XSL template modes to match different "book.01" tags dependent on different XPATH search criteria.

### result.xml

The generated output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="abc.jndi:name=JNDIProp">
        <attribute name="myprop" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings>
                <jndi:binding name="Title">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">abc</jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="Author">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">john</jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings>
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</projects>
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this solution responds to an arbitrary XML input template file.  It appears hard-coded, replacing the template file with a stylesheet, which is not what I understand the original poster is looking for.  If the original poster is given an arbitrary template file with different values in the `@` delimiters, that would require composing another stylesheet.  He does use the phrase "Current Template.xml" implying that it is subject to change.

Comment: @Mark, thanks for your contribution , Since Ken solution has resolved my problem with minor tweaks, I didnt get a chance to play with your solution. However I really appreciate your efforts for taking time and writing this solution.