# variable replacement with value from properties file using xsl analyze string with regex

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Currently i am working on a project that require a variable replacement with a value from properties file, for this usage i thought xsl analyze-string would be a good option for variable replace using regular expression.

This is my source.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
 name="myprops.values:type=Service,name=MyProp">
    <attribute name="Properties">
        <!-- properties for abc.com -->
        book1.dev=@mybook.01@
        <!-- properties for def.com -->
        book1.int=@mybook.01@
        <!-- properties for ghi.com -->
        book1.qa=@mybook.01@
        <!-- properties for jkl.com -->
        book1.prod=@mybook.01@
    </attribute>
</mbean>
<projects>
```

This is my properties.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<variables>
    <variable id="book1.dev">
        <mybook.01>123</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>456</mybook.02>
    </variable>
    <variable id="book1.int">
        <mybook.01>789</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>346</mybook.02>
    </variable>
    <variable id="book1.qa">
        <mybook.01>ab2</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>45ff</mybook.02>
    </variable>
    <variable id="book1.prod">
        <mybook.01>rt67</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>hgj8</mybook.02>
    </variable> 
</variables>
```

This is my current properties.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="props" match="variable/*"
         use="concat(../@id,'&#xd;',name(.))"/>
<xsl:template match="attribute">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../@name"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="@(.*?)@">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="key('props',concat($id,'&#xd;',regex-group(1)),
                      doc('properties.xml'))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

what i am trying to do with this xsl file is to find a string that matches `@(.*)@` in source.xml and replace this with matching property value from properties.xml file.

Please suggest me whether the `<xsl:template match="attribute">` that i am doing in xsl is valid?.
When i run this file i get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
 name="myprops.values:type=Service,name=MyProp">
    <attribute name="Properties">
        book1.dev=

        book1.int=

        book1.qa=

        book1.prod=
    </attribute>
</mbean>
<projects>
```

As per the inputs from @Martin, I am adding additional information:

Source xml is having a variable called : `"@mybook.01@"`

I am trying to get the values of `<mybook.01>` of all variables from properties.xml file to output.xml.

Expected output.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
 name="myprops.values:type=Service,name=MyProp">
    <attribute name="Properties">
        <!-- properties for abc.com -->
        book1.dev=123
        <!-- properties for def.com -->
        book1.int=789
        <!-- properties for ghi.com -->
        book1.qa=ab2
        <!-- properties for jkl.com -->
        book1.prod=rt67
    </attribute>
</mbean>
<projects>
```

Comment: The value of the `name` attribute is `Properties` so when you do `concat($id,'&#xd;',regex-group(1))` the `$id` is `Properties`, yet in your referenced XML document you key on `@id` values like `book1.dev`. That way the `key` call can't find any matching value. I am not familiar with the file format and I am not sure from your post which key definition you want so you will need to explain in more detail which values you want to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="props" match="variable/*"
         use="concat(../@id,'&#xd;',name(.))"/>
<xsl:template match="attribute">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../@name"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([\w.]+)=@(.*?)@">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="concat(regex-group(1), '=', key('props',concat(regex-group(1),'&#xd;',regex-group(2)),
                      doc('test2013081402.xml')))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<projects>
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
 name="myprops.values:type=Service,name=MyProp">
    <attribute name="Properties">
        <!-- properties for abc.com -->
        book1.dev=@mybook.01@
        <!-- properties for def.com -->
        book1.int=@mybook.01@
        <!-- properties for ghi.com -->
        book1.qa=@mybook.01@
        <!-- properties for jkl.com -->
        book1.prod=@mybook.01@
    </attribute>
</mbean>
</projects>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><projects>
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" name="myprops.values:type=Service,name=MyProp">
    <attribute name="Properties">

        book1.dev=123

        book1.int=789

        book1.qa=ab2

        book1.prod=rt67
    </attribute>
</mbean>
</projects>
```

where the `test2013081402.xml` is your properties document

```
<variables>
    <variable id="book1.dev">
        <mybook.01>123</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>456</mybook.02>
    </variable>
    <variable id="book1.int">
        <mybook.01>789</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>346</mybook.02>
    </variable>
    <variable id="book1.qa">
        <mybook.01>ab2</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>45ff</mybook.02>
    </variable>
    <variable id="book1.prod">
        <mybook.01>rt67</mybook.01>
        <mybook.02>hgj8</mybook.02>
    </variable> 
</variables>
```

If you want to preserve the comments then you need to change the template to process the `text` child nodes of `attribute` element nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="props" match="variable/*"
         use="concat(../@id,'&#xd;',name(.))"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attribute/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([\w.]+)=@(.*?)@">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="concat(regex-group(1), '=', key('props',concat(regex-group(1),'&#xd;',regex-group(2)),
                      doc('test2013081402.xml')))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The lastest stylesheet above outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><projects>
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" name="myprops.values:type=Service,name=MyProp">
    <attribute name="Properties">
        <!-- properties for abc.com -->
        book1.dev=123
        <!-- properties for def.com -->
        book1.int=789
        <!-- properties for ghi.com -->
        book1.qa=ab2
        <!-- properties for jkl.com -->
        book1.prod=rt67
    </attribute>
</mbean>
</projects>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, is there any way where we can still remain comments in the output file as is even after processing the file.

Comment: @phani, I have edited my answer to suggest a change to the stylesheet.

Comment: i get this error: XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the third argument of concat()

Comment: I tested the code I posted with the samples I posted with Saxon 9.5 Java. It works for me, I am not sure why you get an error, unless you have changed the XSLT and/or the input. Edit your question to provide the samples you used, and tell us which XSLT 2.0 processor you use.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0, with SAXON-HE 9.5.1-1 version, I haven't changed any thing in xsl file. When I remove `'&#xd;'` from contact string i see no error but getting blank values in output file.

Comment: I will edit and add the sample output I get, that is all I can do for now.

Comment: When I gave you your starting code in response to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195303/how-to-use-profiles-or-targets-to-get-the-values-from-xml-properties-file-using I was expecting you not to change the lookup values.  By removing the delimiter between the two parts of the value in one place, but not the other, you will never find the keyed values, thus you will get the blanks.

Comment: @Ken you can help me in getting together with the above problem and the one that you provided into one xsl file.

Comment: @phani, based on the error message saying "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the third argument of concat" it sounds as if the `key` call (`key('props',concat(regex-group(1),'&#xd;',regex-group(2))`) does not return a single item but several. So that means the definition of the key is not yet correct. As it works for me with the samples provided so far I assume your real input samples are more complex. You would need to show them, perhaps better in a new question.

Comment: my input file is having more than 1000 lines would that be the reason?, Interesting thing is I am seeing the desired output along with this error "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the third argument of concat

Comment: I found the issue, its because duplicate variable names.